# How to suppress git clone output?

Tags: git, shell

**I am running the below command**

```
git clone --quiet ssh://XXXXXXX:29418/git_performance_check
```

**which displays the output as**

> Total 6 (delta 0), reused 5 (delta 0)

How can I totally suppress this output?

Answer (score 16):

Redirect output into the bitbucket.

```
git clone --quiet ssh://XXXXXXX:29418/git_performance_check > /dev/null
```

Comment: I want to calculate the time of this clone command . When I pipe the output to dev/null , the variable does not store  time output.

Comment: My actual command is  Time_clone=\`(/usr/bin/time -f'%e' git clone --quiet ssh://$USER@$host:29418/git_performance_check) 2>&1 >> $log`

Comment: Do the redirection to `/dev/null` within the sub-shell parentheses and it should do what you want I think.